# Toolbar in a new line inside a ToolBarTray

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have two ToolBars in ToolBarTray. Although they can fit in one line, I want to put each ToolBar in new line.
How Can I do that ?

```
<ToolBarTray VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,70,0" Height="65">
    <ToolBar Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="LightGray" >
        <Label>Name :</Label>
        <TextBox Width="120"></TextBox>
        <ComboBox Width="120" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Height="25" Width="80" Background="White" Margin="5,0,0,0">Search</Button>
        <Label>This is a first ToolBar</Label>
        <Button Height="25" Width="80" Background="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always">Look for ..</Button>
    </ToolBar>

        <ToolBar Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="LightGray">
            <Label>Name :</Label>
            <TextBox Width="120"></TextBox>
            <ComboBox Width="120" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN: ToolBar.BandIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.bandindex.aspx):

> The position of the ToolBar in a ToolBarTray depends on the values of
>   the ToolBarTray.Orientation, Band, and BandIndex properties. When
>   Orientation is set to Horizontal, a band represents a row in the
>   ToolBarTray. When Orientation is Vertical, a band represents a column
>   of the ToolBarTray.

In this case, you'll need to set the [ToolBarTray.Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbartray.orientation.aspx) Property to `Vertical`:

```
<ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,70,0" Height="65">
  <etc />
</ToolBarTray>
```

And, don't forget about [ToolBar.Band](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.band.aspx) and [ToolBar.BandIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.bandindex.aspx) Properties:

> If you do not explicitly set this property, its value is determined by
>   the order in which the ToolBar is set in the ToolBarTray. For example,
>   if you put two toolbars in a ToolBarTray without setting the Band and
>   BandIndex properties, the value of Band will be 0 for both toolbars.
>   The value of BandIndex will be 0 for the first toolbar and 1 for the
>   second toolbar.